# Lost trying to use DISTINCT and GROUP BY

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, arel

I'm having trouble with something that I thought would've been simple...

I have a simple model `Statistic` that stores a date (`created_at`), a `user_fingerprint` and a `structure_id`. From that, I'd like to create a graph to show #visitors per day.

So I did

```
@structure.statistics.order('DATE(created_at) ASC').group('DATE(created_at)').count
```

Which works and return what I expect:

```
=> {Sat, 18 May 2014=>50, Mon, 19 May 2014=>90}
```

Now I'd like the same, but I want to squeeze all rows with the same couple (`created_at`, `user_fingerprint`). For instance:

```
|     created_at       | user_fingerprint | structure_id |
|----------------------|------------------|--------------|
| Sat, 18 May 2014 2PM |    '124512341'   |     12       |
| Sat, 18 May 2014 4PM |    '124512341'   |     12       |
| Mon, 19 May 2014 6PM |    '124512341'   |     12       |
```

With this data, I would have:

```
=> {Sat, 18 May 2014=>1, Mon, 19 May 2014=>1}
# instead of
=> {Sat, 18 May 2014=>2, Mon, 19 May 2014=>1}
```

I would be able to do it in Ruby but I wondered if I could directly do it with SQL & Arel.

### Solution regarding your answers

Here is what I did at the end:

```
@impressions = {}
# The following is to ensure I will have a key when there is no stat for a day.
(15.days.ago.to_date..Date.today).each { |date| @impressions[date] = 0 }

@structure.statistics.where( Statistic.arel_table[:created_at].gt(Date.today - 15.days) )
                     .order('DATE(created_at) ASC')
                     .group('DATE(created_at)')
                     .select('DATE(created_at) as created_at, COUNT(DISTINCT(user_fingerprint)) as user_count')
                     .each{ |stat| @impressions[stat.created_at] = stat.user_count }
```

I need to do a bit of Ruby though but that's good for me.

Comment: Why you expect to get just 1 for Sat 18 May? There are 2 records for that user for that day. I do not see enough conditions. structure_id is not used in your question, right?

Comment: I want to store all the records but expect to retrieve only one to have "unique visitors" per day. structure_id is not used because it's scoped by default when I do `@structure.statistics`

Comment: Aha! I will modify my answer to include unique visitors. Look for count(***distinct*** columnname)

Answer (score 1):

your query would look something like (Oracle dialect)

```
select trunc(created_at), user_fingerprint, count(distinct user_fingerprint)
from statistic
group by trunc(created_at), user_fingerprint
```

there is no SQL standard for getting date portion out of datetime data field.

oracle: trunc(dt_column)
sql server: cast(dt_column As Date)
mysql: DATE(dt_column)

Answer (score 1):

```
@structure.statistics.order('DATE(created_at) ASC').group('DATE(created_at)').select('count(distinct(user_fingerprint)) as user_count').first.user_count
```

Comment: It's better to explain *why* your code solves the problem. See [answer].